# How to add a slideshow in drupal 10

Tags: slideshow, drupal-modules

I am unable to add a slideshow in drupal 10

I have installed the view slideshow module and enabled it. Further i don't know how to proceed. In configuration->user Interface it must show views,but its not showing.please help me with this having the clear steps in drupal 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have views slideshow module installed, follow the steps mentioned below.

1. In the View edit page, Select "Slideshow" from the list of available display types.
   Configure the settings for your slideshow, such as the slideshow type, animation, pager, etc. Click on the "Apply (all displays)" button to save the changes.
   Add fields or filters:
2. Add the desired fields or filters to include in your slideshow.
   Click on the "Save" button at the top or bottom of the View edit page to save your changes.
3. Go to the Blocks page (/admin/structure/block) in your Drupal site.
   Find the block corresponding to your slideshow view.
   Configure the block settings, such as the region and visibility.
   Click on the "Save blocks" button to save the changes.

I hope this will help you to achieve the required